# Define class variable in PHP that is not stored along with the object instance

Tags: php, class, object, serialization

I have a simple class:

```
class obj__image extends obj__file {

    public $dimensions;
    public $storedDPI;
    public $colorProfile;

}
```

When i store an instance of this to my session (for example), the object gets serialized and stored away. That's fine.

But is there any way to define a class variable, such as the above `$colorProfile` so that it will not be stored when storing/serializing the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control exactly which properties are included in a serialized object by defining a magic [__sleep()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) method for the class. The __sleep() method should return an array of property names: those property names listed in the array will be included in the serialized object, any other unlisted properties will be discarded